# How to join geojson + CSV file with omnivore leaflet in Mapbox to map data as polygons?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I have two files:
1 geojson file with the country shapes I want for a specific group of countries.
1 csv file with the data I want to map using mapbox.

I'm trying to figure out how can I join these two files so that the geojson country info name matches the countries in my CSV file. I'd like to use omnivore to convert my csv to json and then figure out how to pull that data out to bind in a popup.

There is an example of joining two geojson files (one for shapes and another for data) here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/choropleth-joined-data-multiple-variables/

But I'd like to use Omnivore to parse my csv file so that I can convert CSV first.

I've managed to separately load my geojson country file and load my CSV file making it ready for my highcharts pop-up, but I can't figure out how to join the two by name.

Here's how I've separately called my geojson layer:

```
function popup(feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.name) {
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "countries.geojson",
        success: function(data) {
            $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
                //transitpipes.addData(data);
        var countries = new L.geoJson(data, {
            onEachFeature: popup,
            style: countriesStyle,
        }).addTo(map);


            });
        }
        }).error(function() {});

        });
```

And here's what I'm trying to accomplish with my CSV data:

```
var ckeyOrder = []
var csvGrab2 = $.get('countries.csv',function (response) {
    Papa.parse(response, {
        complete: function(results) {
            var cHeaderRow = results.data[0];
            for (var i = 7; i < cHeaderRow.length; i++) {
            ckeyOrder.push(cHeaderRow[i])
        }
    }
    });
})
csvGrab2.done(function (csvString) {
    var countriesLayer = omnivore.csv.parse(csvString)
    countriesLayer.eachLayer(function(marker) {

        var pieChartOptions = {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {

            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>',
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 60],
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#FFFFFF'],
                        [1, '#E0E0E0']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 1,
                useHTML: true,
                borderColor: '#AAA'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                pie: {

                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    connectNulls: false,
                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                                        style: {
                                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                                        }
                                    }
                }
            }
        };

         pieChartOptions.tooltip.formatter = function() {
                var y = "" + this.y;
                return '<center>' + y + '</center>';
            };
        var cData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < ckeyOrder.length; i++) {
           cData.push(parseInt(marker.feature.properties[ckeyOrder[i]]))
        }

        var lastColumn = ckeyOrder.length;
        pieChartOptions.series = [{
            data: cData
        }];
         // HTML content for country pop-up
        var countryContent = '<div id="popup_template">' +
            '<div>' +marker.toGeoJSON().properties.Name +'</div>' +
            '<div><p>'+marker.toGeoJSON().properties.Production+'</p></div>'+

            '<div id="piechart"></div>';
        var ccontainer = $('<div id="popup_template"/>');
        ccontainer.html( '<div>' +marker.toGeoJSON().properties.Name +'</div>' +
            '<div><p>'+marker.toGeoJSON().properties.Production +'</p></div>' +
            '<div id="piechart"></div>');
        // Delegate all event handling for the container itself and its contents to the container
        ccontainer.find('#piechart').highcharts(lineChartOptions);
        marker.bindPopup(ccontainer[0]);
```

**Is there a way to join my geojson countries with my omnivore parsed CSV code so that I can map my CSV data this way?**

My incredible bad attempt at this mix of code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/t8qsbzs0/

Here is my CSV structure (one row):

```
Country,Production,Gas demand,Total imports,of which LNG,Total exports,Total storage capacity,Share of gas in TPES (%),Self sufficiency (%),Electricity and heat,Industry,Residential,Services,Other
France,0.3,44,47.9,7.8,5,12.1,15.1,0.7,16,26,33,18,7
```

and my countries.geojson file is structured like this:

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"France","iso_a2":"FR","iso_a3":"FRA","iso_n3":"250"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-52.6,2.5],[-52.9,2.1],[-53.4,2.1],[-53.6,2.3],[-53.8,2.4],[-54.1,2.1],[-54.5,2.3],[-54.3,2.7],[-54.2,3.2],[-54,3.6],[-54.4,4.2],[-54.5,4.9],[-54,5.8],[-53.6,5.6],[-52.9,5.4],[-51.8,4.6],[-51.7,4.2],[-52.2,3.2],[-52.6,2.5]]],[[[9.6,42.2],[9.2,41.4],[8.8,41.6],[8.5,42.3],[8.7,42.6],[9.4,43],[9.6,42.2]]],[[[3.6,50.4],[4.3,49.9],[4.8,50],[5.7,49.5],[5.9,49.4],[6.2,49.5],[6.7,49.2],[8.1,49],[7.6,48.3],[7.5,47.6],[7.2,47.4],[6.7,47.5],[6.8,47.3],[6,46.7],[6,46.3],[6.5,46.4],[6.8,46],[6.8,45.7],[7.1,45.3],[6.7,45],[7,44.3],[7.5,44.1],[7.4,43.7],[6.5,43.1],[4.6,43.4],[3.1,43.1],[3,42.5],[1.8,42.3],[0.7,42.8],[0.3,42.6],[-1.5,43],[-1.9,43.4],[-1.4,44],[-1.2,46],[-2.2,47.1],[-3,47.6],[-4.5,48],[-4.6,48.7],[-3.3,48.9],[-1.6,48.6],[-1.9,49.8],[-1,49.3],[1.3,50.1],[1.6,50.9],[2.5,51.1],[2.7,50.8],[3.1,50.8],[3.6,50.4]]]]}},
```

Comment: Can you fix the error on `map.legendControl.addLegend(document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML);` first?see dev console

Comment: Hi sorry @snkashis I left that in after removing the legend. Thanks for looking at this! Here's a cleaner copy: https://jsfiddle.net/t8qsbzs0/4/

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how is that question connected to the Highcharts library?

Comment: @PawełFus I am using the data to chart a highcharts pie graph on popup

Comment: @illusk  can you add your geojson and csv content as external resources stored inside of 2 separate variables so we can avoid the current 404s on load? you can return to ajax logic later.

Comment: @snkashis thanks. I've added _var countriescsv = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/nopop3lnc9tuxlm/countries.csv';_ and _var countriesgeojson = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tif5wvdepqeoxu/countries.geojson';_  to the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/t8qsbzs0/5/  Is this what you mean? Sorry I only have these files locally. Thanks for looking into!

Comment: hey @illusk unfortunately those dropbox links are not usable for what we wanna do - cannot use them as raw content, they present pages to download. do you have a public web server available where you can host those two files, with the proper CORS settings in place, so you can actually use them in the fiddle as you would in production?

Comment: Hi @snkashis ah I see yah I'm sorry I'm a bit new to this and I don't have CORS in place - is it possible to try locally with the files or I'm happy to try to setup CORS

Comment: Also I have my csv and geojson files in the same directory of my html/jus which is what I'm planning for production so it is coded how I plan to deploy it later (if that helps)

Comment: Have failed to setup CORS or allow jsfiddle to call external CSV and geojson files after multiple attempts ... sorry. I hope you can still help me join the geojson and csv files... :D

Comment: Okay, I got you started here with a file at https://gist.github.com/snkashis/3783a5332a7bfd08329d, you need to make some decisions about what exactly your pie chart is supposed to be showing. Check the dev console to see logs.

Comment: Thanks @snkashis I'm still having problems seeing if the data is joined properly from the pop-up on country - I've updated the javascript here: https://jsfiddle.net/k1uusa8f/ It now correctly formats the Highchart piechart data with "name" and "y" for the point name and data. (I only want to plot the last five columns of CSV data in the piechart) The rest I intend to output as HTML on the popup.  The only problem is I can't get anything to show up   when I click on the country (France) now. Don't know if the geojson/marker/country data is correctly linked. Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so yes, once the content of pie chart is decided..this "joining" is pretty easy.

Entire code block is here in a JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/j4fLj5gm/1/
Won't work because of the CORS issue mentioned in comments, but posting it here for anyway.

The join happens with a loop through actual data, and then a search through the Leaflet feature layer to find the match for the country name.

```
for (var countryIndex = 0; countryIndex < countryData.length; countryIndex++) {
  var marker;
  var thisDataRow = countryData[countryIndex];
  var thisCountry = thisDataRow[0];
  countries.eachLayer(function(country) {
    if (country.feature.properties.name === thisCountry) {
      marker = country;
    }
  })
  if (typeof marker == 'undefined') {
    continue;
  }
```

Data prep for the pie chart is quite easy inside each country's loop.

```
  var cData = [];
  var innerIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 9; i < 14; i++) {
     cData.push({name: ckeyOrder[innerIndex],y: parseInt(thisDataRow[i])})
     innerIndex++;
  }

  pieChartOptions.series = [{
      Name: "Production Types",
      data: cData
  }];
```

Results in below screenshot..You will probably want to control a dimensions a bit.
[image]

Comment: thank you! I had to fix a leaflet error and a couple of chart formatting things but I got it working! Thank you.